# My car AC only works at night

Tags: ac, dodge, fan, stratus

My 2004 Dodge Stratus’ AC only works at night when it’s cool. It can do both heating and cooling at night but in the day, it won’t push air at all. When it does turn on, it only works on the 2 highest settings.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the AC not working or is the fan not blowing air on you?

Comment: When did you last have the AC serviced? It needs to be re-gassed around every 3-5 years with new refrigerant.